# Domain Analysis vs System Analysis

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am trying to determine the differences between systems analysis and domain analysis.  It seems that any systems analysis occurs within a domain--so are there techniques, concepts, tools, etc. that a domain analyst would use and a systems analyst would not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Systems Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_analysis) concerns itself with the design and behavior of the entire data processing system (including both computer hardware and software), whereas [Domain Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_analysis) concerns itself primarily with software design within the context of a business domain.

Note the differences in analysis techniques cited in the Wikipedia articles I linked.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I read Wikipedia before askig the question.  I am not seeing a lot in the way of practical differences between the two.

Comment: Systems Analysis concerns itself with the entire hardware and software system, while domain analysis concerns itself with the business domain from a software design context.  Quite mundane, actually; were you expecting something more profound than that?  See also Domain-Driven Design, which doesn't concern itself with hardware either.

Comment: After reading a few more articles...Yeah, was expecting something more profound.  Thx.